# What is the cardinality of $ \{ (A,B) \in \mathbb{P}(E)^2: A \subseteq B \}$ and $ \{ (A,B) \in \mathbb{P}(E)^2: A \cup B = E \}$

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is divided into two questions:

What is the cardinality of $ \{ (A,B) \in \mathbb{P}(E)^2: A \subseteq B \}$ and  $ \{ (A,B) \in \mathbb{P}(E)^2: A \cup B = E \}$.
I find the second one to be easier.

- $C$ = $ |\{ (A,B) \in \mathbb{P}(E)^2: A \cup B = E \}| $

In this problem, we set $|E| = n$, we can notice that $C$ is equal to how many ways we can distribute the $n$ elements of $E$ over $A$ and $B$.

For every elements in $E$, we can either put it in $A$ or $B$, so there are $2$ possibilities for every element of $E$.

Hence there are $2^n$ ways to distribute  the elements. And so $C=2^n$.
Is this answer correct? Because in my solutions sheet I found $3^n$ without any explanations.

As for the first one, I don't know how to approach it.

Can you please help? :)

Comment: Pleaser edit your post to include the actual question in the body.  Don't just leave it in the header.

Comment: To the question:  Each element in $E$ can go into $A=A\cap B$, $B-A$, or neither ($=B^c$).  Can you solve it now?

Comment: @lulu is my answer for the second question correct?

Comment: Yes, but please edit your post so that the body reflects the question(s) you intend to ask.

Comment: @lulu so $C=2^n$? Because in my solutions sheet I found $3^n$ without any explanations.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  In the definition of $C$, are $A,B$ allowed to intersect?

Comment: If $A,B$ can intersect, then each element of $E$ can go to $A-A\cap B, A\cap B, B-A\cap B$, hence $3^n$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, it doesn't matter as long as their union is equal to $E$.

Comment: Then $3^n$ is correct for the reason I gave. If $E=\{1\}$, so $n=1$, the possible cases are $(\emptyset, \{1\}), (\{1\},\emptyset), (\{1\},\{1\})$.  Thus $3$ cases. If $A\cap B$ is required to be empty then the answer is $2^n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133810/discussion-between-mmmmh-mmmmmh-and-lulu).

Comment: Not sure what there is to chat about.  I think my argument is clear...for the first question, each element of $E$ has three mutually exclusive options.  "$A$ and $B$", "$B$ but not $A$", "Neither $A$ nor $B$".  That makes for $3^n$ options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the cardinality of $D := \{ (A,B) \in \mathbb{P}(E)^2: A \subseteq B \}$. For each subset $B\subseteq E$, there are $|\mathbb{P}(B)|$ possibilities for $A$. Of course, the quantity $|\mathbb{P}(B)|$ depends on $|B|$ since $|\mathbb{P}(B)| = 2^{|B|}$. There are $\binom{k}{n}$ subsets $B \subseteq E$ with $|B| = k$, which leads us to :
$$|D| = \sum_{0 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \binom{k}{n} \cdot 2^k$$

Comment: Which, of course, is $(1+2)^n=3^n$.  But, really, it is simpler to just remark that any choice of a good $(A,B)$ pair is determined by a map from $E$ to the set with three elements given by "$A$ and $B$, $B$ but bot $A$, neither".

Comment: @lulu I'd be glad to see a detailed answer using your idea, since I failed to understand what you meant. :)

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Your solution to the second problem is incorrect as you are incorrectly assuming that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  Taking into account the fact that they can intersect, we extend your argument as: a good pair $(A,B)$ is uniquely specified by a map from $E$ to the set with three elements labeled as "$A\cap B$, "$A$ but not $B$", and "$B$ but not $A$.  Hence, $3^n$.

The other problem is much the same. This time we label the three elements as "$A=A\cap B$", "$B-A$ (or "$B$ but not $A$")", and "neither $A$ nor $B$".  Hence, $3^n$ again.

A natural bijection between the two problems cane read off as "$A\cap B$"$\mapsto $"$A\cap B$", "$B$ but not $A$" $\mapsto$ "$B$ but not $A$", and "$A$ but not $B$" maps to "neither".

Phrased differently, given a solution $(A,B)$ to the second problem, we obtain a solution to the first as $(A\cap B,B)$ and given a solution $(A,B)$ to the first problem, we get a solution to the second as $(B^c\cup A,B)$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, why those maps? And how did you get the 3^n exactly?

Comment: The number of maps from a set of $n$ elements to a set with $3$ elements is $3^n$.  There are, after all, $3$ choices for each of the $n$ elements.

Comment: i suggest:  take a particular $n$, not too big.  $n=3$ is probably as far as you want to go.  Now, write everything out explicitly.  I already did $n=1$ for you in the comments. $n=2$ is next.

Comment: I will try that, but can you give a solution similar to that @OliverRoche gave? These are questions of an exam and I don't see how I would have though of using a map.

Comment: The solution @OiverRoche gave is perfectly correct.  One ought to remark that the sum it yields is obviously equivalent to $(1+2)^n=3^n$ and, in my view, the combinatoric argument is better.  But that's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This answer aims at formalizing @lulu's argument above, please give @lulu all credits.

For $A, B \subseteq E$, let $f_{(A, B)} : E \mapsto \{0; 1\}^2$ be the function defined as follows :
For any $x \in E$, the first (resp. second) component of $f_{(A, B)}(x)$ is $1$ iff $x \in A$ (resp. $x \in B$).

Clearly, $(A, B) \mapsto f_{(A, B)}$ is a bijection between $\mathbb{P}(E)^2$ and the set $\big(\{0; 1\}^2\big)^E$ of functions from E to $\{0; 1\}^2$.

We have $A \cup B = E$ iff $f_{(A, B)}(x) \neq (0, 0)$ for all $x \in E$.
Hence, we have a bijection between the set of pairs $(A, B)$ such that $A \cup B = E$ and the set of functions from $E$ to $\{0; 1\}^2 \setminus\{(0, 0)\}$.

Since this latest set has 3 elements, there are $3^{|E|} = 3^n$ such functions, whence the result.

Comment: This approche is too weird. I prefer the combinatorics argument.